# Where to put the express-validation sanitzer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I run an express application which checks on a post route if fields are "ok":

```
const { body, sanitizeBody, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
exports.freelancer_create_post = [
  // Validate fields.
  body('family_name').isLength({ min: 1 }).trim().withMessage('Family name must be specified.'),
  body('date_of_birth', 'Invalid date of birth').optional({ checkFalsy: true }).isISO8601(),
  body('email_address').isEmail().withMessage('Must be a valid email address.'),
  // Sanitize fields.
  sanitizeBody('date_of_birth').toDate(),
  sanitizeBody('email_address').normalizeEmail(),
  sanitizeBody('family_name').escape(),
  sanitizeBody('username').escape(),
(req, res, next) => {...}
];
```

Works fine.
But now I would like to add it to the passport js local strategy middleware chain:

```
const { body, sanitizeBody, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
exports.localStrategy = function (passport) {
    // Configure the local strategy for use by Passport.
    passport.use(new Strategy({
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true,
    },
     [body('family_name').isLength({ min: 1 }).trim().withMessage('Family name must be specified.')],
     (req, email, password, cb) => {...}
    ))
};
```

How would I do that?

I've tried to insert an array in between (see code above), but it returns a `TypeError: this._verify is not a function` error.

Dirty solution is to use the 'mongo-sanitize' module and check each field, but  I would like to understand how to set this up correctly.

Comment: I think that since you use the ' passReqToCallback: true' option then passport expects the req-object to be passed as the first argument in the callback... see here - https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local#parameters and tell me if this solves your problem

Comment: also here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62851981/this-verify-is-not-a-function-on-login   . it seems that you can't provide an array to  passport.use but you can make use of the logic you wanted to add in a callback function that you specified as the following parameter