# this._verify is not a function on login

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, crud, flash-message

I am trying to make a CRUD app for my portfolio. I want the user to be able to sign up and login and then to some stuff once inside (its a calories tracker). The user can Sign Up but when I try to login, I get:

> this.verify is not a function

Here is the login code:

```
// Authenticate Login
app.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate("local", {
        successRedirect: "/myprofile",
        failureRedirect: "/login",
        failureFlash: true
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

The passport.js

```
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy,
      bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

// User Model
const User = require("../models/user");

module.exports = function(passport) {
    passport.use(
        new LocalStrategy({usernameField:"username"}, {passReqToCallback: true}, (username, password, done) => {
            // Check if there is a user with this username
            User.findOne({
                username: username
            }).then(user => {
                    if(!user) {
                        return done(null, false, {message: "There is not a user with this username"});
                    }
                    // Check if the password is correct
                    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                        if(err) throw err

                        if(isMatch) {
                            return done(null, user)
                        } else {
                            return done(null, false, {message: "Password is invalid"})
                        }
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        })
    );

    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
            done(err, user)
        })
    })
}
```

If someone is interested or you need some more code I can of course post it, I am not sure what else to include. But if you are feeling like it, here is the link to the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Cortoloman/caloriesTracker).

Thank you for all your help,
Stay well and healthy

Edit1: Fullstack of the question (or I hope this is it)

```
TypeError: this._verify is not a function
    at Strategy.authenticate (C:\Users\Dell Vostro 3885\Documents\Programming\PersonalProjects\CalorieTracker\node_modules\passport-local\lib\strategy.js:90:12)
    at attempt (C:\Users\Dell Vostro 3885\Documents\Programming\PersonalProjects\CalorieTracker\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:366:16)
    at authenticate (C:\Users\Dell Vostro 3885\Documents\Programming\PersonalProjects\CalorieTracker\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:367:7)
    at C:\Users\Dell Vostro 3885\Documents\Programming\PersonalProjects\CalorieTracker\app.js:187:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Dell Vostro 3885\Documents\Programming\PersonalProjects\CalorieTracker\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Dell Vostro 3885\Documents\Programming\PersonalProjects\CalorieTracker\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Dell Vostro 3885\Documents\Programming\PersonalProjects\CalorieTracker\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Dell Vostro 3885\Documents\Programming\PersonalProjects\CalorieTracker\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Dell Vostro 3885\Documents\Programming\PersonalProjects\CalorieTracker\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Dell Vostro 3885\Documents\Programming\PersonalProjects\CalorieTracker\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Dell Vostro 3885\Documents\Programming\PersonalProjects\CalorieTracker\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at methodOverride (C:\Users\Dell Vostro 3885\Documents\Programming\PersonalProjects\CalorieTracker\node_modules\method-override\index.js:79:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Dell Vostro 3885\Documents\Programming\PersonalProjects\CalorieTracker\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Dell Vostro 3885\Documents\Programming\PersonalProjects\CalorieTracker\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\Dell Vostro 3885\Documents\Programming\PersonalProjects\CalorieTracker\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Dell Vostro 3885\Documents\Programming\PersonalProjects\CalorieTracker\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
```

Comment: Can you please show the full stack of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the option `passReqToCallback` passport expects the `req`-object to be passed as the first argument in the callback:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'passwd',
    passReqToCallback: true,
  },
  function(req, username, password, done) {
    // request object is now first argument
    // ...
  }
));
```

See [this](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local#parameters) for more information.

Comment: Thank You! Could I bother you some more? Right now, I just removed this option and it works. In the link it says that I would use this option if I wanted the verify callback. What would you use this for? Is this another request you make to verify what the user entered?

Comment: Honestly I'm not quite sure but maybe you'd need it if you wanted to perform some additional checks on the `req`-object.